# My bbPress rewrite rules aren't working

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm using bbPress, and bbPress uses the rewrite so that:

`index.php?bbp_user={id}` becomes `/forums/users/{login}`

I want to change/add it so that it's: `/forums/members/{id}`

The reason is that some users' login is their email, so we don't want that in the URL of the profile page.

I have the code to change the links working:

```php
function bbp_custom_author_link(  $url,  $user_id,  $user_nicename){
    $url = site_url()."/forums/members/".$user_id;
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'bbp_get_user_profile_url', 'bbp_custom_author_link', 10, 3);
```

But I keep getting 404 errors when you click the link. I'm trying to add a rewrite rule to fix it, but it's not working:

```php
function bbp_custom_author_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "^forums/members/([^/]*)$",
        'index.php?bbp_user=$matches[1]',
        "top"
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'bbp_custom_author_rewrite', 10);
```

I'm still getting 404 errors. I tried adding `flush_rewrite_rules();` and re-saving permalinks, but it didn't change.

I think it has to do with redirecting to a bbPress URL, because if I change `bbp_user` to `page`, I do get a redirection to the page with that ID. But when trying to redirect to the profile page, it fails.

**UPDATE**
I installed a couple of rewrite rule debugging plugins and they both show that the query is correct, but I still get a 404. It's like bbPress isn't loaded at the time of the redirect:

[image: debugging results]

Comment: You'll need to enquire in bbPress's support channels, but I suspect it's the result of the `bbp_user` query variable being set up to query based on user login - by rewriting to provide that qv a user ID instead the query fails, akin to how `WP_Query` would if you passed the `pagename` qv a post ID instead of a slug. With any luck bbPress will have some other qv you can use which will execute their query based on user ID instead.

Comment: @bosco BBPress is an official project on .org so it _is_ on topic, albeit rarely asked about, the same with BuddyPress, it's the same umbrella that makes the .WP nightly/beta testing plugin and the Gutenberg plugin on topic

Comment: I retract my vote and eat my words! It looks like the `bbp_user` qv does accept a user ID as well

Comment: I think my problem has more to do with bbPress not being available at the time of redirect, but the address seems to be set up correctly. See my update

Comment: have you tested that `index.php?bbp_user=1` works?

Comment: `index.php?bbp_user=1` works when permalinks are set to plain. It doesn't work when permalinks are set to something else.

Comment: For some reason, this works `forums/members/{login}`. There must be something in bbPress that changes that last part from id to login

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the rewrite rule uses an invalid regular expression. It's important to run your rewrite rules through a rewrite rule testing plugin to check that it actually matches the URL you want to use. You don't need to guess the result then refresh on the frontend to test that it works or not.

As for the regex itself, importantly none of the slashes are escaped.

I used https://regexkit.com/php-regex to test this with `123` as the ID, without escaping on the slashes the URLs did not match. A URL with trailing or starting slashes also did not match

Comment: Please see my note. I think it's something other than the regex.